# MS Access Multiple IF Statement

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm not sure why the following code is giving me incorrect answers in MS access:

```
IIf([Due Date]-[Receipt Date] Between "15" And "100000","15 + days before due date",
IIf([Due Date]-[Receipt Date] Between "7" And "15","Less than 15 days before due date",
IIf([Due Date]-[Receipt Date] Between "0" And "7","Less than 7 days before due date",
IIf([Due Date]-[Receipt Date]  < 0,"After due date")))) AS [Timely Receipt]
```

Please help

Comment: For starters, you could format it for the audience...

Comment: You put quotes around your numbers. They are treated like text. Your "BETWEEN" is being determined lexicographically, not numerically. As an example "6" is between "300" and "89". Take the quotes off your numbers and the problem should go away.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that direct substraction would give you the desired response.

You should use function Datediff, i.e. DateDiff("d", [Due Date], [Receipt Date])

You compare int with string - which is not needed. Would be better if you remove the quotes around numeric values in this case.

Comment: Yes it was the quote issue. I removed it and it worked. Thank you for your response!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Switch(
DateDiff(d,[Due Date],[Due Date])>=15 AND  DateDiff(d,[Due Date],[Due Date]) <= 100000, "15 + days before due date",
DateDiff(d,[Due Date],[Due Date])>=7 AND  DateDiff(d,[Due Date],[Due Date]) < 15, "Less than 15 days before due date",
DateDiff(d,[Due Date],[Due Date])>=0 AND  DateDiff(d,[Due Date],[Due Date]) < 7, "Less than 7 days before due date",
DateDiff(d,[Due Date],[Due Date])<0, "After due date"
) As [Timely Receipt]
```